# Calculating a position of an associative array

Tags: php

I have a loop which counts through all Products and prints them with a special methode. The size of each methode is the maximum of loops for each methode.
This is what I need:

```
loop=1 -> methode=print_box_simple
loop=2 -> methode=print_box_5
loop=3 -> methode=print_box_5
loop=4 -> methode=print_box_5
loop=5 -> methode=print_box_5
loop=6 -> methode=print_box_5
loop=7 -> methode=print_box_2_full
loop=8 -> methode=print_box_2_full
loop=9 -> methode=print_box_4
loop=10 -> methode=print_box_4
```

loop is the counter of the products. I need to sum it up by size somehow. Heres the code I started off with:

```
// Get layout by position
$box_layout = self::getLayoutByPosition(self::$layout, $counter);
...
    private function getLayoutByPosition($layout, $counter) {
    // The necessary code
    }
    // The layout array
    private $layout = array(        1=>array('methode'=>'print_box_simple', 'size'=>1), 
                                    2=>array('methode'=>'print_box_5', 'size'=>5),
                                    3=>array('methode'=>'print_box_2_full', 'size'=>2),
                                    4=>array('methode'=>'print_box_4', 'size'=>4),
                                    5=>array('methode'=>'print_box_2_half', 'size'=>2)
    );
```

I hope its clear what I meant.

Comment: Sorry, but your goal is anything but clear. What products, how do you loop, what do you mean by "sum it up somehow"?

Comment: `sum(array_column($array,'size'))` ?

Comment: @Scuzzy So you have a masters degree as a clairvoyant?

Comment: @arkascha I work with outsourced developers, just going to leave that there.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose something like this should work:

```
// if you need a certain limit of operations then:
$layout_limit = 10;
$counter = 0;

foreach ($this->layout as $item) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $item['size']; $i++) {
        // calling method, named in `methode` key
        $item['methode']();

        $counter++;
        if ($counter == $layout_limit) {
            break 2;  // 2 so as to break `for` and `foreach`
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$i = 0;

    foreach($array as $key => $sub_array){

        if($sub_array['size'] > 0){

            for($j = 0 ; $j < $sub_array['size'] ; $j++){
                $i++;
                echo 'Loop = '.$i.' -> methode = '.$sub_array['methode'].'<br/>';
            }

        }


    }
```